# Using Powershell to enter results in a specific cell of a CSV

Tags: powershell

I have a CSV file and the last column (Column J) has usernames in it.
I have a script that will run down column J and display the State by pulling the info from active directory.
I want it to add the information to column K beside the current username.
Below is the script.  It works fine to get the information I just can’t get it to add it to column K.
I placed a count function (the line that says $add1 = $add1 +1) with the hope I could find a solution that would let me pipe the results to my CSV file in Column K row $add1.  I assume there is a way to do it but cant figure it out.
Thanks

```
enter code here



Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$add1 = 1
Import-csv C:\Temp\newfile.csv | Select -expand MUID | ForEach {          
$add1 = $add1 +1   
Get-ADUser -Identity $_ -Properties st | select -ExpandProperty st

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
import-csv C:\Temp\newfile.csv | %{

    $k = Get-ADUser -Identity $_.MUID -Properties st | select -ExpandProperty st
    $_ | add-member -MemberType noteproperty -Name k -Value $k
    $_
}  | export-csv -NoTypeInformation C:\Temp\newfile2.csv
```

If the csv already had column k, you just have to assign the result you want to `$_.k`

Comment: This looks like it will work.  And far more easyly then i could have hoped for. So thanks. But i am scared of add-mamber.  Forgive me i am new.  add-mamber does not ad anything to AD does it?

Comment: @Ron - No it has nothing to do with that. It is adding a member to the csv object and piping to another csv.

Answer (score 0):

You can `Select-Object` to add the column with a calculated property:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

Import-csv C:\Temp\newfile.csv | `
Select-Object *,@{n='k';e={ (Get-ADUser -Identity $_.MUID -Properties st).st }} | `
Export-Csv .\users.csv -NoTypeInformation
```